# TomEE server seems to want to use sun's implementation of jsf

Tags: java, jsf, apache-tomee

My TomEE app gets the following exception on startup. Im not sure where (or how) its configured to use suns implemenatation of jsf.

I have apache jsf jars under my TomEE installation, which is 
apache-tomee-webprofile 1.5.2 bundle. I'm just not sure where to start? I'd have thought it would attempt to use Myfaces jars.. but cant see where/why its attempting to use sun's implemenatation?

```
Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
```

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Comment: insightful.. never thought to look there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what the problem was .. very early on the startup process, in my console, I saw the following message at INFO level (I had assumed it was ok to ignore this as it wasn't warn/error)..

INFO: validateJarFile(D:\WORKSPACE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\testeroo\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-web-api-6.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Followed some time later, (and pages of console output...)

SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
```

A quick google of "jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class".. told me to remove that jar javaee-web-api-6.0.jar from my Eclipse project (as TomeEE has its own).. That got rid of the INFO message.. and tadaah.. the app deployed